# Unresolved attribute warnings when inheriting from GenericViewSet in Django with custom Mixin

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, pycharm

I'm using Django and Django REST Framework to develop a web application. I have a custom ViewSet called ProductsViewSet that inherits from CreateAndSaveUserMixin, RetrieveModelMixin, and GenericViewSet. The code is as follows:

```
class ProductsViewSet(CreateAndSaveUserMixin, RetrieveModelMixin, GenericViewSet):
    queryset = Product.objects.none()
    serializer_class = ProductsSerializer
```

The CreateAndSaveUserMixin is defined as:

```
class CreateAndSaveUserMixin:

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data, context=self.get_serializer_context())

        if serializer.is_valid():

            if isinstance(request.user, Cognito):
                response = serializer.save(created_by=request.user)
            else:
                response = serializer.save()

            return JsonResponse(self.serializer_class(response).data, safe=False)

        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

The issue I'm experiencing is that my IDE, PyCharm, shows the following warnings when I'm working with the CreateAndSaveUserMixin:

Unresolved attribute reference 'serializer_class' for class 'CreateAndSaveUserMixin'
Unresolved attribute reference 'get_serializer_context' for class 'CreateAndSaveUserMixin'
Although my application functions correctly, the editor doesn't recognize these attributes that come from the base class GenericViewSet, which I'm inheriting in my view rather than in my mixin.

How can I resolve these warnings in PyCharm and ensure that the editor correctly recognizes the inherited attributes from GenericViewSet in my CreateAndSaveUserMixin?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

i tried declare serializer_class and get_serializer_context in the custom mixin like:

`serializer_class = None get_serializer_context = None`

but only works for serializer_class